# Ruby if statement with spreadsheet gem not working correctly?

Tags: ruby, excel, if-statement, rubygems

I'm very new to Ruby, and I thought if statements would be intuitive, but apparently I'm missing something.

I have an .xls file that I'm reading with the spreadsheet gem.
The file looks like this:

Starting at row 2 (with three columns) (row 1 has headers - username, id, count):

```
bob         abc   1
bob         abc   2
bob         abc   3
bob         abc   4
kevin       abc   5
kevin       abc   6
kevin       abc   7
ciara       abc   8
ciara       abc   9
ciara       abc   10
kate        abc   11
kate        abc   12
kate        abc   13
```

I have the following code to figure out how many users there are:

```
def self.number_of_users
    _sheet = @book.worksheet(0)
    _reference_row = _sheet.row(1)      #rows are zero index based in spreadsheet gem
    @users += 1                         #initialized to 0 at beginning of class
    _sheet.each 1 do |row|              #starting the do each at row 2 of .xls
      if row[0] != _reference_row[0]    #[] for column access
        @users += 1
        puts row[0]                     #print statements for check
        puts _reference_row[0]          #...
      end
    end
    puts @users
end
```

Instead of getting 4 printed at the end, I'm getting 10!! I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, reference[0] keeps 'bob'. Update reference_row.

```
def self.number_of_users
    _sheet = @book.worksheet(0)
    _reference_row = _sheet.row(1)      #rows are zero index based in spreadsheet gem
    @users += 1                         #initialized to 0 at beginning of class
    _sheet.each 1 do |row|              #starting the do each at row 2 of .xls
      if row[0] != _reference_row[0]    #[] for column access
        @users += 1
        _reference_row = row            ### UPDATE _reference_row here
        puts row[0]                     #print statements for check
        puts _reference_row[0]          #...
      end
    end
    puts @users
end
```

Or you can do it like this. It's more likely Ruby way.

```
def self.number_of_users
    sheet = @book.worksheet(0)
    puts sheet.row(1..-1).map(&:first).uniq.count
end
```

- row(1..-1) gets rows from 1 to last (-1 means like sheet.size() -1)
- map(&:first) gets first item in Array
- normally we don't use underscore for instance val nor private val like Java